# connection to server explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008

i need to connect to the server explorer in visual c# 2008 express edition.i am unable to find the server explorer.instead there is database explorer.How can i connect to the server explorer then....??

Answer (score 0):

In express editions, that window's name is database explorer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x603htbk%28VS.80%29.aspx